# Is it possible to change the Wi-Fi network of an already configured Raspbian installation?

Tags: wifi, raspbian-lite

I have a Pi with Raspbian Lite installed but no keyboard or screen to use with it.
I changed my router and don't remember the old Wi-Fi name/pxd.

Is it possible to edit the SD card to change the default network name/pwd?

Comment: Do you remeber which version of Raspbian Lite you installed? Do you have access to a PC (or another Pi) that can access the second partition on the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a new `wpa_supplicant` in the boot partition for the new network.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

For most models you can also plug in an Ethernet cable.

It is always possible to modify the system directly on any Linux system.

Comment: placing a new wpa_supplicant file in the boot partition indeed changed the WI-FI settings